# Async/Await Function, fs.readfile and store it to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs

```
const fs = require('fs');
// const util = require('util');

let text = ``;

const files = [`head.txt`,`body.txt`,`leg.txt`,`feet.txt`];
let head,body,leg,feet = ``;
//const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

function isCompleted(err,data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    text = data.toString();
    proceedData()
}

function proceedData() {
    console.log(text);
    return text;
}

function readFileBody() {
    fs.readFile(files[1], 'utf8', isCompleted);
}

async function printFiles () {
    //head = await fs.readFile(files[0], 'utf8', (err,data) => {if (err) {throw err;}else {head += ` ${data}`}});
    body = await readFileBody();
    //await fs.readFile(files[2], 'utf8', isCompleted);
    //await fs.readFile(files[3], 'utf8', isCompleted);


}
printFiles();
```

When I console.log(body) in the global scope, it will return an undefined.
When I console.log(body) in the local printFile function (without return), it will return an undefined too, but I console.log(text) in local isCompleted, it will return a value of text file.

How do I store a value of text file to the variable?

Answer (score 13):

`fs.readFile` does not return a promise, and even if it did, you're not returning it, that's why `body` is undefined. And you're mixing callbacks with promises. Either drop `isCompleted` or `await`.

To use it with `await` you can use `util.promisify` to convert a callback based function into a promise based one.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const readFIle = promisify(fs.readFile);

function readFileBody() {
    return readFile(files[1], 'utf8');
    // ^^ you need to return the promise
}

async function printFiles () {
    body = await readFileBody();
}
```

In node >= 10 you can use `fs/promises` to avoid `promisify`

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

function readFileBody() {
    return fs.readFile(files[1], 'utf8');
}
```